# Does being bijective and having a full rank jacobian Matrix imply being a Diffeomorphism?

Tags: analysis, inverse-function-theorem

I was thinking it to be true, as the inverse function theorem gives us contious differentiablity of the inverse locally at any point. With continous differntiablity being a local attribute of the function, the inverse should be continous differentibale right?

Comment: I'm not sure this even warrants an answer: Yes, your reasoning is completely correct.